# Is default move constructor optimized away by compiler?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an [std::multimap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) of the following type:

```
 typedef std::multimap<std::pair<bool,uint32_t>, FooObject>
```

The **FooObject** has default move copy and assign constructors declared:

```
   FooObject(FooObject&& v) = default;
   FooObject& operator=(FooObject&& other)=default;
```

The copy/assign constructors are private to disable implicit copy.

So I should be able to emplace a pair into the map like this:

```
mymap.emplace(std::make_pair(false,32),FooObject());
```

This throws a list of errors with the one at the end:

> error C2660: 'std::pair::pair': function does not take
>   2 arguments

If I declare move copy assign constructors without "default"
then it compiles ok.

```
   FooObject(FooObject&& v){}
   FooObject& operator=(FooObject&& other){}
```

Why is that? Does the compiler optimize away these constructors when marked with "default" keyword? I am using MSVC140

**UPDATE:**

Based on the comments below I found the reason - FooObject has a non-copiable member instance.
Here is the FooObject:

```
#define NO_COPY_ASSIGN(TypeName)   \                                                     
  TypeName (const TypeName &);     \                                                                
  void operator= (const TypeName &);

class FooObject
{
private:
   NO_COPY_ASSIGN(FooObject)
public:
    struct FooStruct
    {
        FooBuffer   frameBuffer;   //<--Here it is
    }fooStruct;

    FooObject(){}


    /** Move constructor to allow insert into vector without copy */
    FooObject(FooObject&& v) = default;
    FooObject& operator=(FooObject&& other) = default;

};
```

*FooBuffer has also its copy/assign private.But I still don't get why replacing 'default' with {} fixes that.Please explain.

Comment: Presumably `FooObject` has a member that is not moveable and thus the compiler won't generate default move operations for it. Could you show us a full (small) example of the code we can copy-paste into an editor and compiler ourselves?

Comment: Can you give us a [mcve]?

Comment: @NathanOliver I added an example of the above mentioned FooObject.

Comment: Please show `FooBuffer`.

Comment: @NathanOliver In the FooBuffer will take me time to hide commercial code,but in terms of its design it has its copy and assign constructors private.No move constructors at all,and one default empty constructor.No inheritance.

Comment: What types of data members does `FooBuffer` have? Do you still get the same problem if you use an `int` instead of a `FooBuffer`?

Comment: @DanielH that's right. FooBuffer was the problem as it is non-copyable. Replacing with some POD works fine.

Comment: Non-copyable and non-movable are different things. Is `FooBuffer` also non-movable?

Comment: Nope.It is only non-copyable.

Comment: If you have `= default` then you also have support for `= delete`, which is a *much* better way of disabling the copy functions.

Comment: @BenVoigt completely agree,that's the pre c++11 era chunk :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between

```
FooObject(FooObject&& v) = default;
```

and

```
FooObject(FooObject&& v){}
```

Is that the former will emit a constructor that moves each member from `v` while the latter default constructs each member and does nothing with `v`.

Since `FooBuffer` is not movable that means that the compiler will delete `FooObject(FooObject&& v) = default;` as it would be ill-formed.

With `FooObject(FooObject&& v){}` you do not have that problem as you never try to move the members of `v`.  Since there is no member initialization list the compiler will add one for you that just default constructs the members.

You can see this behavior more explicitly with this:

```
struct Moveable
{
    Moveable() = default;
    Moveable(Moveable&&) { std::cout << "in Moveable(Moveable&&)\n"; }
};

struct Foo
{
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(Foo&&) = default;
    Moveable m;
};

struct Bar
{
    Bar() = default;
    Bar(Bar&&){}
    Moveable m;
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    Bar b;
    std::cout << "test_f\n";
    Foo test_f(std::move(f));
    std::cout << "test_b\n";
    Bar test_b(std::move(b));
}
```

which outputs

```
test_f
in Moveable(Moveable&&)
test_b
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71c943ca65e794d8)</kbd>

Showing that nothing is actually moved in `Bar`'s move constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that one of the member of `FooObject` is not move-able, which prevents the compiler from generating default move operations.

The `{}` versions of the move operations you implement yourself *do no work* (specifically: they don't actually do a move operation) on the members of `FooObject` and are thus legal.